# Is there anyway to get the values of some controls in other form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway to make the imagination? Like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action1", "controller1"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyTextBox)
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("action2", "controller1"))
{
   <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
}
```

My model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string MyTextBox { get; set; }
}
```

and Action2:

```
public ActionResult Action2(MyModel m)
{
   ViewBag.Value = m.MyTextBox;
   return View();
}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: What is your purpose or what do you wants to achieve ?

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, *kinda*, you could use JS to populate a hidden field in the other form with whatever value is typed into the textbox on the other form.

Comment: As @James stated, the only way to share across 2 forms is via client script to sync to a hidden field. Another option is to have the same form going to the same action, but use 2 submit buttons, and define the submits as `<input type="submit" name="SubmitType" value="A" />` to capture in the action which of the submit buttons was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use client script to tie the fields together as the user performs the update - nothing server or view side. The example is using JQuery, but you could whatever flavor you prefer.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action1", "controller1"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyTextBox, new { data_sync_target = ".MyTextBox-dest" })
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("action2", "controller1"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyTextBox, new { @class = "MyTextBox-dest" })
    <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
}

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[data-sync-target]').keyup(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).data('sync-target'));
            $target.val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```